# Как удалить элемент(картинку) при перетаскивании на другой элемент(картинку) Drag'n'Drop

Tags: javascript

Как удалить элемент(картинку) при перетаскивании на другой элемент(картинку) Drag'n'Drop
Как удалить мяч(мяч двигается) при перетаскивании на ворота помогите пожалуйста

```js
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");

ball.onmousedown = function(e){

    var coords = getCoords(ball);
    shiftX = e.pageX - getCoords(ball).left;
    shiftY = e.pageY - getCoords(ball).top;

    ball.style.position = "absolute";
   moveAt(e);


    document.body.appendChild(ball);

    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;

    

    function moveAt(e) {
        ball.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + "px";
        ball.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + "px";
    }


    document.onmousemove =function (e) {
        moveAt(e);
    }

    ball.onmouseup= function(){
        document.onmousemove = null;
        ball.onmouseup=null;
    }

  
}
ball.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };
  function getCoords(elem) {   // кроме IE8-
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: box.top + pageYOffset,
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
    };
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://isplit.ru/image/cache/data/brendy/Leco/street_plus_300_h_200_sm/street_plus_300_h_200_sm_1-630x630-0.jpg" alt="" srcset=""  width="200" height="200">


  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="" srcset="" id="ball" width="100" height="100">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш вопрос решается обычной проверкой, все функции для решения задачи у нас есть. Нам нужно сделать так, чтобы когда мяч попадал на ворота, мы его удаляли, для этого воспользуемся событием `onmouseup`, оно нам скажет когда мы отпустил наш мяч, а после этого мы проверим, или наш мяч попал в зону ворот, для этого посчитаем эту зону: `var widthGoal = coordsGoal.top + goal.width, heightGoal = coordsGoal.left + goal.height;`, и того готовый код:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById("ball");
  var goal = document.getElementById("goal"); 

  ball.onmousedown = function(e){

    var coords = getCoords(ball);
    shiftX = e.pageX - getCoords(ball).left;
    shiftY = e.pageY - getCoords(ball).top;

    ball.style.position = "absolute";

    moveAt(e);

    document.body.appendChild(ball);

    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;

    function moveAt(e) {
      ball.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + "px";
      ball.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + "px";
    }


    document.onmousemove =function (e) {
      moveAt(e);
    }

    ball.onmouseup= function(){
      document.onmousemove = null;
      ball.onmouseup=null;
      
      var coordsGoal = getCoords(goal),
          coardBall = getCoords(ball);

      var widthGoal = coordsGoal.top + goal.width,
          heightGoal = coordsGoal.left + goal.height;

      if (coardBall.top < heightGoal && coardBall.left < widthGoal) {
        // Выполняем все что нам угодно
        ball.remove();
      }
    }


  }
  ball.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };

  function getCoords(elem) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: box.top + pageYOffset,
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
    };
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://isplit.ru/image/cache/data/brendy/Leco/street_plus_300_h_200_sm/street_plus_300_h_200_sm_1-630x630-0.jpg" alt="" srcset=""  id="goal" width="200" height="200">


<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="" srcset="" id="ball" width="100" height="100">
```

Добавляю еще один вариант решения задачи (в комментариях обсуждалось дополнительное количество мячей, которые будут располагаться рандомно). Для того чтобы рандомно расположить элементы, воспользовался 'Math.random() * (max - min) + min'. В общем, код нужно дорабатывать, потому что временами вылазит ошибка, но думаю Вам будет интересно разобраться почему, и как все это происходит. Ах да, еще один момент, первому мячу совсем плохо, поэтому он стоит на месте, думаю разберетесь.

Мой совет Вам, прежде чем задавать вопрос, стоит поработать над задачей самому, иначе смысл в этом всем? **Удачи в изучение.**

Код:

```js
var ball = document.getElementById("ball"),
        goal = document.getElementById("goal");

    createAndCopyBall(ball, 5);

    function controllerBalls() {
        document.onmousedown = function (e) {
            // Получили координаты текущего положения мяча
            var coords = getCoords(e.target);
            // Обработали нужные нам данные
            var shiftX = e.pageX - coords.left,
                shiftY = e.pageY - coords.top;

            moveAtLocal(e);

            function moveAtLocal (e) {
                e.target.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + "px";
                e.target.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + "px";
            }

            document.onmousemove = function (e) {
                moveAtLocal(e);
            };

            e.target.onmouseup = function () {
                document.onmousemove = null;
                e.target.onmouseup = null;
                if (checkCoords(e.target)) {
                    e.target.remove();
                }
            }
        };

        document.ondragstart = function () {
            return false;
        };
    }

    function createAndCopyBall(ballObject, countBalls) {
        var body = document.querySelector('body');
        // Первоначальному мячу контроллер тоже надо =)
        controllerBalls(ballObject);

        for (var i = 0; i < countBalls; i++) {
            var copiedBall = ballObject.cloneNode();
            // Получилили координаты текущего положения мяча
            var coords = getCoords(copiedBall);
            // Обработали нужные нам данные
            var shiftX = copiedBall.x - coords.left - getRandomArbitary(100, 1000),
                shiftY = copiedBall.y - coords.top - getRandomArbitary(100, 1000);
            // Указали абсолютное позиционирование
            copiedBall.style.position = "absolute";
            // Указали стартовые координаты
            moveAt(copiedBall, copiedBall, shiftX, shiftY);
            // Добавили в DOM дерево
            body.appendChild(copiedBall);
            // Назчаем контроллер для мяча
            controllerBalls(copiedBall);
        }
    }

    function checkCoords(ballObject) {
        var coordsGoal = getCoords(goal),
            coardBall = getCoords(ballObject);

        var widthGoal = coordsGoal.top + goal.width,
            heightGoal = coordsGoal.left + goal.height;

        if (coardBall.top < heightGoal && coardBall.left < widthGoal) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    function moveAt(e, ballObject, shiftX, shiftY) {
        ballObject.style.left = e.pageX !== undefined ? e.pageX : e.x - shiftX + "px";
        ballObject.style.top = e.pageY !== undefined ? e.pageY : e.y  - shiftY + "px";
    }

    function getCoords(elem) {
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
        return {
            top: box.top + pageYOffset,
            left: box.left + pageXOffset
        };
    }

    function getRandomArbitary(min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
```

```css
 .ball {
      z-index: 1000;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://isplit.ru/image/cache/data/brendy/Leco/street_plus_300_h_200_sm/street_plus_300_h_200_sm_1-630x630-0.jpg"
     alt="" srcset="" id="goal" width="200" height="200">

<img src="https://realrussianclub.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/football-157930_640.png"
     alt="" srcset="" id="ball" class="ball" width="100" height="100">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: можешь плз помочь а как добавить чтобы несколько мячей было и все можно было двигать?

Comment: Да, могу, только уже завтра =)

Comment: получилось самому, а как их рамдомно расположить помоги пожалуйста?

Comment: ниже код находится

Comment: @recile сейчас все будет

Comment: я изменил, сча отображаются , их надо как то рамдомно мячи расположить, а то не получается

Comment: @recile я стараюсь написать хороший код, уже почти дописал. И да, мячи рандомно будут

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88530/discussion-between-dmitry-and-recile).

Comment: спасибо  еще раз, проблема в том что его надо создавать в js а который в html он так и остается не подвижный

Comment: я просто его скрыл тот мяч img:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
        }

Answer (score 0):

Решение вопроса по комментарию. (*можешь плз помочь а как добавить чтобы несколько мячей было и все можно было двигать?*)

Добавление дополнительных мячей, результат: 
просто добавить

```
 ball= e.target;
        ball.classList.contains('ball1');
```

```js
var goal = document.getElementById("goal"); 

  document.onmousedown = function(e){

    ball= e.target;
    ball.classList.contains('ball1');

    var coords = getCoords(ball);
    shiftX = e.pageX - getCoords(ball).left;
    shiftY = e.pageY - getCoords(ball).top;

    ball.style.position = "absolute";

    moveAt(e);

    document.body.appendChild(ball);

    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;

    function moveAt(e) {
      ball.style.left = e.pageX - shiftX + "px";
      ball.style.top = e.pageY - shiftY + "px";
    }


    document.onmousemove =function (e) {
      moveAt(e);
    }

    ball.onmouseup= function(){
      document.onmousemove = null;
      ball.onmouseup=null;
      
      var coordsGoal = getCoords(goal),
          coardBall = getCoords(ball);

      var widthGoal = coordsGoal.top + goal.width,
          heightGoal = coordsGoal.left + goal.height;

      if (coardBall.top < heightGoal && coardBall.left < widthGoal) {
        // Выполняем все что нам угодно
        ball.remove();
      }
    }


  }
  document.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
  };

  function getCoords(elem) {
    var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
    return {
      top: box.top + pageYOffset,
      left: box.left + pageXOffset
    };
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://isplit.ru/image/cache/data/brendy/Leco/street_plus_300_h_200_sm/street_plus_300_h_200_sm_1-630x630-0.jpg" alt="" srcset=""  id="goal" width="200" height="200">


<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="" srcset="" id="ball" width="100" height="100">
<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="ball.svg" srcset="" id="ball" width="100" height="100" class="ball1">
<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="ball.svg" srcset="" id="ball" class="ball1" width="100" height="100">
<img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1000459/2436/i/450/depositphotos_24366251-stock-photo-soccer-ball.jpg" alt="ball.svg" srcset="" id="ball" class="ball1" width="100" height="100">
```